# interview question of hypothesis test: how many tests are needed to tell the difference between an unfair coin (p=0.49) and a fair coin (p=0.5)

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Here is an interview question of hypothesis test:

> how many tests are needed to tell the difference between an unfair coin ($p_1=0.49$) and a fair coin ($p_2=0.5$)?

My idea is constructing the normal sample to use `Independent two-sample t-test`.

We denote the Bernoulli distribution of k-th coin (k = 1, 2) for i-th test: $T_k(i)\sim Bernoulli(p_k).$ Then

$$B_k(i)=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^nT_k(i)}{n}\sim N\left(p_k,\dfrac{p_k(1-p_k)}{n}\right).$$

However $B_k(i)$ is not a i.i.d. sample (variance changes), which prevents us from using independent two-sample t-test.

**Edit:**

I think the question is not clear, however for my opinion, it hopes us to test the difference of two binomial means. Therefore I think we should use `Independent two sample Z test` for binomial samples:
$$H_0: p_1 = p_2 = p,$$
$$Z = \dfrac{\hat{p}_1-\hat{p}_2}{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})\left(\dfrac{1}{N_1}+\dfrac{1}{N_2}\right)}.$$

And the value of $N_1,N_2$ (we can simply assume $N_1=N_2=N$) depends on the confident level.

Comment: It depends on how confident you want to be about your decision

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty answer, which is what many interview questions seek:

The width of a 95% CI for $p$ is $1.96\sqrt{p(1-p)/n} \approx \sqrt{1/n}$ in close two-person races. So in public opinion polling $n = 2500$ subjects gives margin of error about $\pm 2\%. $

Here margin of error is about 1%, so $n\approx 10\,000.$

Somewhat more formally, one might insist on using
sample size large enough to reject $H_0: p = 0.49$ against $H_a: p > 0.49$ for specific alternative $p = 0.50.$ It turns out that $30\,000$ suffices to get
good power, as shown by the following simulation in R:

```
set.seed(919)
pv = replicate(10^5, 
  prop.test(rbinom(1,30000,.49), 30000, alt="less")$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.96614      $ aprx power of test
```

Comment: Though there's a bit of ambiguity in the question - do we have just the $p = .49$ coin and need to get a confidence interval for its true probability that excludes $.5$, or do we get two coins with true (but unknown) probabilities $p = .49$ and $p = .5$ and need to get a confidence interval for their *difference* in probabilities that excludes zero?

Comment: I agree the question is unclear (as are many interview questions). I think the idea here is to understand that the answer is in the thousands. // You might argue that you want margin of error $0.5\%$ to distinguish clearly btw .49 and .50. That would argue for $n=40,000$ // Perhaps more precisely one should look for 90%ish power in a test of $H_0; p=.49$ vs $H_a: > 0.49)$ and seek power against alternative 0.50. I'm adding that to my answer. In a _one-sided_ test about $30000$ suffices for power over 90%.

Comment: I agree that the question is not clear. I think we should test the difference of means. Please see my update